# Connect Monitor to Physical Server, but have VM on server detect it

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a built server, with multiple VMs running on it. There is one user account running on the physical server, and on that session, there are multiple VMs running. I use VMware Workstation, to run the VMs, and then I remote to each one as necessary from other boxes.

I would like to connect a monitor to the physical server, but I don't want the one account with all the VMs to detect it. Instead I would like one of the VMs to detect the monitor. And when I remote to that VM, my monitor takes over the monitor connect to the server.

Does any one know how to do this? I'm thinking of a configuration in VMware Workstation to enable one of my VMs to detect to monitor. But I'm not sure how and I don't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is impossible, as this means the host's graphics driver needs to support such a feature.  You can't simply skip the host's graphics driver. Well, if you could, that would be a serious security vulnerability, or a sheer violation of engineering principles.

Comment: A "violation of engineering principles" aside, if this theoretically were possible, how would one go about out doing it?

Comment: Like I said earlier, "the host's graphic driver needs to support it". I have no idea if VMWare will place nice, even if you found a driver to support such functionality. You are better off just VNC into the VMs.

Comment: If you can get PCI-e passthough to work then you can allocate a PCI-e card to the Vm only. Do that with a PCI-e graphics card and you have monitor output controlled only by the VM.

This is tricky to do and you will need VT-d and a card with an IOMMU (some gforces, mostly prof. ones. All AMD cards, ....)